# xml DOM documentElement property

Tags: javascript, xml

here is my probs :

```
    xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(cloneNode);//here documentElement  required
    xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;//here documentElement required
```

again here,

```
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0] works same as     
xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("book")[0];

    x.appendChild(newel);//here documentElement not required

    xmlDoc.createElement("edition");//here documentElement not required


    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book')[0];//here documentElement not required
    cloneNode=x.cloneNode(true);//here documentElement not required
    xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(cloneNode);//here again required
```

My question is how can i  know when to use documentElement property?In what condition i should use documentElement property or where should i use it .How can i know when this property is required.

Answer (score 2):

The XMLDocument represents the document, which is one level above the root element, when you wants to add a child then you need to append it to an element.

In this case you want to add the child to the root element which is obtained from the document property `xmlDoc.documentElement`

Comment: is it so?But here it works fine xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book')[0];//xmDoc here is xml document

Comment: because it is a query which can be executed from the top layer, but to add a element you need to access the right element to which the child has to be added

Comment: can u plz provide me a link that states your answer

Answer (score 0):

xmlDoc is something you can't use.  You need to get the root element of the xmlDoc before you can start searching the xml--that's what documentElement returns.

Comment: but here it works fine xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book')[0];

Comment: @Maizere, Post your loadXMLDoc() function.

Comment: If loadXMLDoc() returns the documentElement, then your should probably rename your xmlDoc variable to root.  Because you say xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book')[0] works fine, then it seems clear that loadXMLDoc() does in fact return the documentElement (or the root element) of your xml.  That means you do not need to write xmlDoc.documentElement to append anything to the root node.